# What order are these subsets listed in?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, subset, discrete-mathematics

I am writing a program to list of all subsets of a string.  My program (which is given below) lists the subsets of "abcd" in this order:

```
'' 'd' 'c' 'cd' 'b' 'bd' 'bc' 'bcd' 'a' 'ad' 'ac' 'acd' 'ab' 'abd' 'abc' 'abcd'
```

Which is correct.  However, the reference solution lists them in this order:

```
'' 'a' 'b' 'ab' 'c' 'ac' 'bc' 'abc' 'd' 'ad' 'bd' 'abd' 'cd' 'acd' 'bcd' 'abcd'
```

My question is: **what is the name of this ordering?**

For reference, here is my program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
   This class generates subsets of a string.
*/
public class SubsetGenerator
{
   public static ArrayList<String> getSubsets(String word)
   {
       ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
      //fill out
       //result.add("");
       if(word.length() == 0)
       {

           result.add("");
        }

   else
    {
        String notFirst = word.substring(1);
        ArrayList<String> smaller = getSubsets(notFirst);
        //System.out.println(smaller);
        char first = word.charAt(0);

        result.addAll(smaller);

        for(String i: smaller)
        {
            result.add(first+i);
        }
    }


   //simpleSubsets = getSubsets(simple+word.charAt(0));

  // Form a simpler word by removing the first character
  // fill out

  // Generate all subsets of the simpler word
  // fill out

  // Add the removed character to the front of
  // each subset of the simpler word, and
  // also include the word without the removed character
  // fill out

  // Return all subsets
  return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: what's the specific order ? and what your results refer to ? and why the correct output you got is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The ordering that they're producing is the order you'd get if you counted off in binary and translated the numbers 0 and 1 to a, b, c, and d:

```
d c b a | set
--------+----
0 0 0 0 | {}
0 0 0 1 | {a}
0 0 1 0 | {b}
0 0 1 1 | {a, b}
0 1 0 0 | {c}
0 1 0 1 | {a, c}
0 1 1 0 | {b, c}
0 1 1 1 | {a, b, c}
1 0 0 0 | {d}
1 0 0 1 | {a, d}
1 0 1 0 | {b, d}
1 0 1 1 | {a, b, d}
1 1 0 0 | {c, d}
1 1 0 1 | {a, c, d}
1 1 1 0 | {b, c, d}
1 1 1 1 | {a, b, c, d}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I fixed my program, but I still cannot wrap my head around how this binary ordering works. I don't see a pattern in the 0's and 1's. Could you explain in a little more detail? I am very new to this type of ordering

Comment: Nevermind I just remembered that I learned this in my Discrete Math class. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Binary ordering is just like decimal ordering, really, if you are missing eight fingers." --Tom Lehrer